# How to use a different loss for different image types in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two kinds of images, whose names start with two different strings respectively (e.g 'a_....' and 'b_...'). I want to use a different loss function based on which image I am currently training on (batch size of 1). How can I include an `if` condition to use a particular loss for an image?

Thank you !

Comment: why not train with a_.. pictures, change the loss function and continue training with b_... pictures? You could even switch after every batch

Comment: are you using fast-ai python library by any chance ? can you specify which library and which method you want to add this loss function ?

Comment: You should put the "a_..." and "b_..." meta information inside the data you're processing (you can use tfrecords for that). Then, you can use conditional switches such as `tf.cond`

Answer (score 1):

try read and use ternary_operators in python (exist in any programming languages) http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html
for examle if i understand you

```
def los_func_1():
    print 'los_func 1 '

def los_func_2():
    print 'los_func 2'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_1 = True
    los_func_1() if use_1 else los_func_2()
```

this code will print

> los_func 1

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Yes I can, but my issue is how to get the `use_1=True`